# Lync mobile client's behaviour

Tags: iphone, lync-2013

I have a test Lync 2013 onprem installation, everything works fine both from inside and outside, however the Lync Client for iphone does not function as supposed. I checked debug logs on all servers and see nothing that could cause the behaviour. The strange thing is that a functionality I am testing is actually working, the problem is that it disconnects on every action.
So, the scenario is as following
- User 1  is logged on Lync Client on Windows 7 - LAN
- User 2 is logged on on Lync Mobile on Iphone - public internet

User 1 sees presence of User 2
User 1 sends IM message to User 2 - no errors
User 2 successfully recieves the message - gets an error "Failed to process the server respons" and appears offline
User 2 signs out of Lync Mobile and signs back In- no errors
User 2 sends IM message back to User 1 - gets an error "Failed to process the server respons" and appears offline
User 1 recieves the IM message - no error

Any glues anyone? Where to look?

Thanks in advance

Emin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, was a buggy release of Lync Server, installing updates (latest CUs) solved the issue